# Django query JSONField where the value is equal to {}

Tags: django

I have a model with a JSONField like this:

```
metadata = JSONField(
    _('Metadata'),
    blank=True,
    default=dict,
    help_text=_('Multi key-value field to hold any additional information'),
)
```

Is there any way in Django to query for objects where `metadata` is equal to `{}`? I use Django 2.1.

Comment: which DB are you using? MYSQL?

Comment: Did you try **`MyModel.objects.filter(metadata={})`** ?

Comment: @JPG: I use PostgreSQL. I was certain I had tried the obvious `.filter(metadata={})` and received errors but now it seems to work. If you add that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this

```
MyModel.objects.filter(metadata={})
```

**Reference**: Querying [**`JSONField`** in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)